# Null Pointer Importing Gradle Project Into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, gradle, libgdx

I used libGDX to generate some gradle projects that I now need to import into Eclipse. So, I opened Eclipse, installed the gradle plugin, and went to File -> Import -> Gradle Project.
At that point, I chose the directory that contained my generated gradle projects. Then, I clicked 'Build Model' and then added my projects to the list of available projects to import. After I select 'Finish' Eclipse begins importing them. Right at the very end I get this dialog:

[image]

Looking in the log file, I found this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.wizards.GradleImportOperation.refreshProjects(GradleImportOperation.java:256)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.wizards.GradleImportOperation.perform(GradleImportOperation.java:195)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizard$1.doit(GradleImportWizard.java:66)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:49)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I've tried reinstalling everything relevant. I've created the projects several times. I've downloaded a fresh version of eclipse. But, the same issue occurs everytime. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it turns out, when importing a gradle project, there is a field called "Run After" which defaults to "afterEclipseImport". This doesn't exist unless it is defined in the project you are importing. The documentation says that if it doesn't exist then the gradle import project skips over it. Well, once I unchecked this option, the import worked correctly.

Edit: Just as an aside. This assumes that your project is in a subdirectory inside your workspace as opposed to the workspace directory itself. (See the other answer).

Answer (score 11):

In case it helps someone else in the future, I had the same problem, but a different resolution. My issue was resolved when I moved the projects out of the eclipse workspace directory. It can be in another directory entirely, or in a subdirectory.

**BROKEN**:

```
/path/to/workspace/.metadata
/path/to/workspace/build.gradle
/path/to/workspace/core
/path/to/workspace/etc
```

**WORKS**:

```
/path/to/workspace/.metadata
/path/to/workspace/projects/build.gradle
/path/to/workspace/projects/core
/path/to/workspace/projects/etc
```

I did not need to remove the "afterEclipseImport" script. See this issue: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1537#issuecomment-38535167

Comment: Had the same issue.
As Steve says, all it takes is placing the gradle/libgdx files in a subdirectory of the workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with eclipse 2019-03 and gradle 5.3.1.

In the end I created a new workspace and I was then able to import the gradle project.

Originally I had a workspace and tried to create a second gradle project from within eclipse but it failed trying to synchronise with gradel.

I also tried moving the project out of the workspace dir but it still refused to import.